# What is the item "What are you?" good for?

Tags: sir-you-are-being-hunted

While looting a solitary house in an industrial biome I found an item looking like a ragdoll. The item is named *"What are you?"*. It can't be used or equipped, only discarded. It has the tag "Mysterious" which is usually reserved for story-critical items. Is it somehow important or does it serve any purpose?
[image: Screenshot of mysterious item]

Comment: Do you try it on the stone, where you bring shards? Also, it could be unimplemented feature, as if game still in development.

Comment: @Dracontis I tried. The stone did react to it like it reacts on any other non-fragment item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found an answer. It's a [talisman](http://siryouarebeinghuntedwiki.com/wiki/Talisman), currently have no use, but will be power ups in future. There are several species of such dolls.

As for the comment. On this [kickstarter page](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1499900830/sir-you-are-being-hunted/posts/354813) of this game this dolls is given as purchase present. There are confirmation that they will (in game) increase slightly some stats and as there are only 3 toy-dolls, then, I think, in game will be 3 dolls too.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you have a source of the claim that they will have power ups in the future? Do you know how many species there are?

Comment: @Philipp, made some research again and found what you've asked. See updated answer.